# Set AIR window position programmatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, window, air

How do you set the position of an AS3 AIR Project window programmatically?

It is simple to do with application descriptor, but I cannot get it to work through code.

All research has lead me to `stage.nativeWindow.x = 200;` but this does not do anything for me.

The following has no effect:

```
    public function Main():void 
    {
        stage.nativeWindow.x = 200;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try placing the code in an event handler:

```
protected function initWindowPosition(event:Event):void {
  stage.nativeWindow.x = 200;
}
```

and listen to an event, such as [Event.ACTIVATE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#event%3aactivate):

```
addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, initWindowPosition);
```

If that doesn't work on it's own, you might also try using the [NativeApplication's activeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#activeWindow) property, in case the stage's `nativeWindow` property isn't initialized at the time the ACTIVATE is dispatched:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.x = 200;
```